# Why won't Visual Studio 2005 generate an Xml Serialization assembly?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, xml-serialization, sgen

Why isn't Visual Studio 2005 generating a serialization setting when I set the project setting "Generate Serialization Assembly" to "On"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[It turns out that Dev Studio only honors this setting for Web Services.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164303.aspx)

For non-web services you can get this to work by adding an AfterBuild target to your project file:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="AssignTargetPaths;Compile;ResolveKeySource" Inputs="$(MSBuildAllProjects);@(IntermediateAssembly)"  Outputs="$(OutputPath)$(_SGenDllName)">         
      <SGen BuildAssemblyName="$(TargetFileName)" BuildAssemblyPath="$(OutputPath)"  References="@(ReferencePath)" ShouldGenerateSerializer="true" UseProxyTypes="false" KeyContainer="$(KeyContainerName)" KeyFile="$(KeyOriginatorFile)" DelaySign="$(DelaySign)" ToolPath="$(SGenToolPath)">
          <Output TaskParameter="SerializationAssembly" ItemName="SerializationAssembly" />
      </SGen>
  </Target>
```

See also:

- [SGen MSBuild Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164303.aspx)
- [AfterBuild Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzw8335a(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: +1 for this help, Adam! As a follow up question, is adding the SGen task to a project considered a best or worst practice? I'm hoping that it speeds up the performance of my app.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done manually with [sgen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240(VS.80).aspx).